# An error in the LinkList code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linked-list

.cpp file

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "LinkX.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

LinkX::LinkX(int pid,char *pname)
{
    id=pid;
    strcpy(name,pname);
    next=null;
}

void LinkX::displayLink()
{
    cout<<id<<endl;
    cout<<name<<endl;
}
```

the above code gets the error :

> Error 3   error C2511: 'LinkX::LinkX(int,char *)' : overloaded member
>   function not found in 'LinkX'

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             LinkX *L1=new LinkX(10,"Charvi");
             LinkX *L2=new LinkX(20,"Vin");
             L1->next=L2;

             delete L1;
             delete L2;
         }
    };
```

This code gets the errors:

> Error 1   :error C2664: 'LinkX::LinkX(int,char)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 2 from 'const char [7]' to 'char' Error 2   :error C2664:
>   'LinkX::LinkX(int,char)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char
>   [4]' to 'char'

What do these errors mean ?

How can I correct them?

These codes were written in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first error,

Did you declare the `LinkX::LinkX(int pid,char *pname)` constructor in the class declaration (in your `LinkX.h` file)?

Concerning the second error:

Your constructor ask for a `char*` variable, indicating that it needs to modify it.
When you call it, you use constant char arrays, that cannot be modified.
Has your constructor does not realy need to modify the `pname` variable, you only have change the `pname` type to `const char*` and it will be ok.

Comment: I was able to resolve the first error with your help,Thankyou!                                But I didn't quite get your explanation for the second error?Can you further explain it.

Comment: I reolved the first two errors,but I still get this error                                                                                                                    Error 1 error C2511: 'LinkX::LinkX(int,char *[])' : overloaded member function not found in 'LinkX'

Comment: In C++ a variable can be alterable or constant. A variable is constant if tagged with the `const` keyword.
In the other hand, hard coded vaues are always constants, such as `42` or `"foobar"`.

A `char*` is a pointer on an non-constant `char` memory. It means that, with this pointer, you should be able to modify the memory.
But your hard coded value `"Charvi"` is constant, so the compiler with consider a `const char*` pointer in order to protect the pointed memory.

So there was a conflict between your constant value and your constructor that ask for a non-constant pointer.

Comment: In your first post, you mentionned `LinkX::LinkX(int,char *)`. Now you tell us about `LinkX::LinkX(int,char *[])`.
So your problem should be the second parameter: `char *[]` is equivalent to `char**` and not `char*`.

Comment: Yes Thankyou so much for your help,I resolved the error.Thanks again!